# MacVim and rails plugin - missing menu

Tags: vim, ruby-on-rails-3, macvim

I have installed rails.vim on MacVim and everything is working correctly, that is I can use the extra functions in Vim.  The problem is that the Plugin menu doesn't have the rails plugin.  Is there an easy way to add it to the main menu?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the menu is disabled for mac versions of vim.  To turn it on, edit ~/.vim/plugin/rails.vim line 63 to read:

```
call s:SetOptDefault("rails_menu",has('menu'))
```

I've made a github fork with this change, available at https://github.com/existentialmutt/vim-rails